# Como reproduzir um video do youtube em um iframe? Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe, youtube

Estou tentando reproduzir um vídeo do youtube em meu Site usando `iframe` e está me gerando o erro que está no titulo da pergunta.

## HTML:

```
 <div class="video-container">
     <iframe
        src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65Iz_GKbhHk"></iframe>
  </div>
```

## Web.Conf:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Obs:** Adicionei ao arquivo de configuração a opção `X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN"`

- O que há de errado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apenas abra o vídeo no YouTube e clique em Compartilhar, logo acima da descrição. Abrirá um painel com a opção Incorporar, clique nela. Você será apresentado a um código HTML, basta copiar e colar no seu site. Lá ainda é possível customizar o player.

Por exemplo, para o vídeo que você passou, o código gerado é esse:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/65Iz_GKbhHk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

---

Por que o seu código não funciona?

O YouTube não permite que a página toda seja inserida em algum site. É possível apenas fazer um iframe com a incorporação específica do player, o que é ideal.

Ele faz isso inserindo um cabeçalho HTTP na página completa, o `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN`, que instrui os navegadores a não carregar a página se o requisitor for de um domínio diferente. [Saiba mais sobre esse cabeçalho no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options). Isso que você colocou no web.conf apenas proíbe os outros sites de colocar o seu site num iframe.