# Autoplay video do youtube no mobile

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Gostaria de saber como posso colocar o video do youtube em autoplay no celular, pois não está funcionando, no mobile ele não fica em autoplay, não roda o video sem ter que apertar.

Meu Script.

```
   <script>      
          // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
          var tag = document.createElement('script');
          tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

          // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
          //    after the API code downloads.
          var player;
          function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
              playerVars: { 'modestbranding':0,'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,'autohide':2,'wmode':'opaque','showinfo':0,'rel':0,'loop':0,'disablekb':1,'playlist':1,'playerapiid':0,'enablejsapi':1,'list':1,'listType':1, 'iv_load_policy':3 }, 
              videoId: 'RC0Wrd12sno',
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }


            });


          }


          // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
          function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.mute(true);
             event.target.loadPlaylist(['RC0Wrd12sno']);
             event.target.setLoop(true); 
          }


</script>
```

Comment: O que tem tentado fazer? Mostre o seu código.

Comment: então, ele funciona perfeitamenta no web mas nao funciona no mobile, eu nao consegui achar nada para colocar autoplay quando é mobile

Comment: Eu não usei a API do google em um siste que fiz, usei iframe veja:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80969/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin.

Comment: eu ja tentei usar apenas o iframe, mas não da para deixar mudo o video sem utilizar o api, que é o que eu fiz ali em cima, mas ele nao quer ter autoplay no celular.

Comment: você já olhou no console se tem algum erro?