# Problemas com iFrame e X-Frame-Options Header

Tags: html, iframe, http-request, request

Eu estava iniciando um simples projeto porém quando vou utilizar o `<iframe>` ocorre um problema, o problema da pagina a qual eu estou *requisitando* não aparece.

Eu dei uma procurada sobre o assunto e achei algumas pessoal falando sobre `X-Frame-Options Header` porém não entendi se isso resolveria meu problema ou iria bloquear sites externos de 'requisitar' meu site como `<iframe>`, mas não desisti e tentei utilizar `<meta>`, no entanto não tive o resultado desejado.

**Meta o qual eu utilizei**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="DENY">
```

Comment: O `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` bloqueia o uso de frames, se você QUER usar frames então o remova-o. Se o mesmo assim não aparece o conteudo o problema pode ser qualquer coisa, por exemplo você está usando `//site.com/` em uma página com protocolo `file:///` ou problemas de ssl, ou no teu html (erro de digitação). Então se você não der detalhes, não tem como responder. Leia este link para entender como criar um exemplo do problema que os outros consigam reproduzir e assim possam lhe ajudar: [COMO CRIAR UM EXEMPLO MÍNIMO, COMPLETO E VERIFICÁVEL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Uma boa noite amigo!

Comment: Fiz um pergunta pouco tempo sobre, veja se pode te ajudar.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80969/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin

Comment: Só pra corrigir o `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` com `deny` é que bloqueia os frames.

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi com a seguinte configuração:

> Adicionar a linha ao arquivo referente à seu domínio: servidor_nome.com.conf

(Servidor APACHE2):

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL"
```

(Servidor NGINX):

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL";
```